# Can someone explain the divisions in StarCraft 2 for me?

Tags: starcraft-2

Another question I've had:  When viewing a player's ranking in Starcraft 2, it tells you their rank in their "division."

- **Why are players segregated into divisions?**
- **Do the divisions really *mean* anything?**  Are the lower/higher rated divisions better?

  - Are you more likely to be placed with/against players from your division?
  - Can you move from one division to another?  Can I choose one?
- How do you move up within your division?
- How many divisions are there, and/or how many players can be in one division?
- How do you view other players in your division?

If these should be asked as individual questions, please let me know.

Comment: Related question asked today: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6621/in-starcraft-2-are-points-comparable-across-leagues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divisions are just a segment of a League, they don't really mean anything at all. You will play with people from many different divisions while you are playing.

When you qualify for a league, you are randomly placed into whatever division is currently being filled.

All the divisions do is break the people up into groups of around 100, and give you a rank to strive for. You shouldn't ever change division until you change league. And your league will change as you do well or poorly in your current league.

They poll your skill randomly and decide weather or not to bump you one way or the other.

You can on occasion have matches against people from other leagues, to test your skill level.

Lots more info here: http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/League_%28StarCraft_II%29

Answer (score 9):

> Why are players segregated into divisions?

To make you have a more localized group of people to compare yourself to.  It's fairly arbitrary, but moving up within the division is a good motivator to make you want to keep playing.

> Are you more likely to be placed with/against players from your division?

Not really.  This depends on player availability, and even if division-mates are favored by the matchmaking service, you will very rarely get a chance to play against someone in your own division.

> How do you move up within your division?

Winning games can net you anywhere from 2 to 50 points depending on your bonus pool and the strength of your opponent.  Your rank in your division is based on the number of points everyone has.  Losing matches makes you lose points and move down in the division in a similar way.

> Can you move from one division to another? Can I choose one?

The only way to change divisions is by qualifying for another league, either moving up or down.  You will be automatically assigned; you cannot choose your division.

> How many divisions are there, and/or how many players can be in one division?

There can be up to 100 players in any division.  The game will create as many divisions as it needs to fit everybody who played their placement matches into one.

> Do the divisions really mean anything? Are the lower/higher rated divisions better?

Nope.  The divisions are largely irrelevant.

> How do you view other players in your division?

If you go to your leagues screen, you can click on the league you want to view everyone in your division.  You can also view other players' divisions from their profiles.

Answer (score 2):

Players are in a Division of 100 people in the same League.  These people are randomly selected.  Though you are not more likely to play within your division than the rest of our league, you are more likely to play in your league than other leagues.

Division rank is sorted by points.

You cannot change divisions without also changing leagues.  Whenever you change a league you will change divisions (there is no mapping of divisions between leagues).

Divisions have no intrinsic value other than to give you 99 people to compare against from your league.

On your ladder screen there is an option to view your division.

Select your ladder here:

[image]
brings up this later here:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

There are about 1 million players on starcraft 2 so you can't have say 100 000 players roosters, that's why they divided it.

For a [complete ranking of everyone go there](http://www.sc2ranks.com/)